# How to prevent the compiler from optimizing memory access to benchmark read() vs mmap() performance?

Tags: c, io, mmap

I would like to benchmark read() vs mmap() performance of a C program reading 10GB of data. If I have read or mmap'ed the data to a buffer, what should be done in order to make sure the data was actually read?

At the moment I use the following function after each single read() and after the one mmap() operation to make sure data is actually in memory:

```
void use_data(void *data, size_t length) {
    volatile int c = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        c += *((char *) data + i);
    }
}
```

However, I feel this might even introduce overhead? Maybe one can even distinguish between read() and mmap():

In the read() case I think no explicit data access is needed, because the read() call will copy the data to a buffer anyway. In the case of mmap() however, I think some kind of summing up/counting need to be performed in order to make the kernel load every page.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I hope you're only planning to target 64-bit...

Comment: Yes, 64bit architecture

Comment: Why don't you simply `int use_data(...)` and return `c`. No need to declare it volatile.

Comment: I was told the compiler could recognize the type would overflow and optimize that

Comment: Have you considered just compiling with optimization disabled?  I don't know a compiler that fails to have such an option.  Often it is spelled `-O0`, though you should check your documentation if you are unsure.

Comment: Then declare it `unsigned`, which is allowed to overflow, and has exact semantics in that case, making it legal and preventing its removal by the compiler. (Aside: How does the compiler know the sum of all the bytes in those 10G will be more than INT_MAX, or less than INT_MIN?)

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Sure, only then the whole benchmark is completely useless. **Never benchmark without optimizations**. How useless would that be?

Comment: On the contrary, @EOF.  The library functions to be benchmarked are already compiled with whatever optimizations are relevant.  Optimization of the benchmark driver code is irrelevant, and potentially harmful.  Building the test program with optimization off disables only those optimizations that are a risk to interfere with the result of interest.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: If you want to benchmark something, you should try to make it as large a part of the runtime of the tested program as possible, otherwise it'll get swamped by fluctuations in the peripheral code. So compile your test harness with full optimizations.

Comment: @EOF, alternatively, you eliminate as much of the harness as possible, for instance by removing code required only for optimization-busting.  And/or you narrow the timed section of the code as much as possible.  Either way, for a test like this, if optimization significantly changes the proportion of measured time consumed by the harness then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: a few years ago, I was working on a project that used bubble memory.  (I.E. there were a lot of successive same instruction passed to the bubble memory) (I.E. port = 'a';) Any optimization would result in the compiler eliminating all but one of the statements.  marking the port as volatile did not stop the elimination of the repetative code.  So, for each such section, optimization had to be off.  Fortunately, there was an available pragma to turn optimization off/on.  I.E. optimization is not ALWAYS a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to access the volatile variable for each byte you process. Sum all bytes into a local. Then, write the sum into a volatile variable.

In fact you don't need a volatile variable. You can use any opaque sink that the compiler cannot prove as unneeded. Writing the sum to a temp file would be guaranteed to work as well.

Note, that this is not just a hack to make the compiler cooperate. This is guaranteed to touch every byte (because it could influence the result). The result is needed for an external IO. This cannot be optimized away under the standard.

If alignment allows, sum in bigger units such as 32 or 64 bits. Use unsigned types to avoid UB on overflow. You want to be memory/IO bound, not ALU bound. You can create instruction-level parallelism by summing multiple independent streams using multiple local accumulator variables.